# I migrated a PHP server and I'm not able to solve this error below

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

I use phpMyAdmin and MySQL version is: 8.0.36

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1525 Incorrect DATE value: '' in...`

I saw some other questions about this, but none fixed my problem.

I tried to run some SQL commands Like:

`ALLOW_INVALID_DATES.`
`set optimizer_switch="derived_condition_pushdown=off";`

Comment: Either do  `SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`  or add it to the mysql.ini/cnf

Comment: It would be better to provide a valid date value when you insert or update data.

Comment: But the error comes from a SELECT * FROM

Answer (score -1):

You can't set the date field value with a blank string(''). You need to add a condition here that if your field value is blank, add the value as null.

**For eg.**

```
$date_field = $date_field ? $date_field : null
```